# <?PHP, REGEX and me. A tragedy in three acts

Tags: php, regex

long time listener. First time caller...

Not strictly a PHP question as it involves regular expressions but this one has got me tearing my hair out.

I have 3 regular expressions that I want to create, and only one is working correctly.

Now I am not sure whether this is due to the fact that:

1. I don't understand preg_match and
   ereg and their return codes as I
   haven't worked in PHP for about 7
   years.
2. My regular expressions are
   just plain wrong.
3. I am mentally disabled.

Either way here are the expressions and my feeble attempts in making them work.

1) Match any number starting with 2,3,4 or 5 then followed by 5 digits. (This one I think works)

code:

```
if (!ereg('/[2-5]\d{5}/', $_POST['packageNumber' )
{
   echo "The package number is not the correct format.";
}
```

2) Match any number starting with 2,3,4 or 5 then followed by 5 digits then a period then a 1 or a 2.

```
if (!ereg("/[2-5]\d{5}\.[1-2]/", $_POST['packageModifier' )
{
   echo "The package modifier is not the correct format.";
}
```

3) Match any combination of alphanumerics, spaces,periods and hypens up to 50 characters.

```
if (!ereg("/[0-9a-zA-Z\s\-\.]{0,50}/", $_POST['customerNumber' )
{
   echo "The customer number is not the correct format.";
}
```

If anyone can please tell me what I am doing wrong I'll give them my first born.

Comment: Unbalanced parentheses/brackets in the conditional.

Comment: And `$echo` should read just `echo`.

Comment: Get an editor that highlights syntax errors. If you don't understand how functions work, feel free to read their manual pages on php.net.

Comment: sorry that was my super quick refactoring.

Comment: @Török: sorry but I rather felt that your added tags 1) could be deemed offensive 2) didn't offer additional value and 3) didn't apply anyway, hence I removed them.

Comment: The last pattern can be rewritten as, "/^[\w \-.]{0,50}$/", which gives alpha-numeric (case-insensitive) characters in less space.  Plus, \s will match spaces or underscores, the latter you didn't mention.

Comment: @Wicked, \s matches any of the ASCII whitespace characters: [ \t\n\r\f\v]. It's \w that matches underscores.

Comment: Bear in mind that `ereg()` and related functions are deprecated. You should always use the `preg_xxx()` functions for regex in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you just missed off the closing ] on the $_POSTS and i've added in anchors for the start and end of the lines and used preg_match.

If you don't anchor it and the pattern is matched anywhere in the string then the entire thing will match. For example.

"dfasfasfasfasf25555555as5f15sdsdasdsfghfsgihfughd54" would be matched if the first one was not anchored.

**Number One**

```
if (!preg_match('/^[2-5]\d{5}$/', $_POST['packageNumber'])) {
 echo "The package number is not the correct format.";
}
```

**Number Two**

```
if (!preg_match('/^[2-5]\d{5}\.[2-5]$/', $_POST['packageModifier'])) {
  echo "The package modifier is not the correct format.";
}
```

**Number Three**

```
if (!preg_match('/^[0-9a-zA-Z\s\-.]{0,50}$/m', $_POST['customerNumber'])) {
 echo "The package modifier is not the correct format.";
}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, yes the syntax errors were just a result of my quick refactoring of the code in the SO input box.

Comment: As a side note, if you need to generate this stuff all the time I recommend using a program called RegexBuddy. Very good good and you can test it live and it generates the code for you for multiple languages.

Answer (score 8):

You are mixing up [PCRE functions](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) and [POSIX regular expression functions](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ref.regex.php). You are using a [Perl-Compatible regular expression](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php) with a POSIX regular expression function.

So replace `ereg` by `preg_match` and it should work:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[2-5]\d{5}$/', $_POST['packageNumber'])) {
    echo "The package number is not the correct format.";
}
if (!preg_match("/^[2-5]\d{5}\.[1-2]$/", $_POST['packageModifier'])) {
    echo "The package modifier is not the correct format.";
}
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z\s\-.]{0,50}$/", $_POST['customerNumber'])) {
    echo "The customer number is not the correct format.";
}
```

Along with fixing the PHP syntax errors I added anchors for the start (`^`) and the end (`$`) of the string to be matched.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to anchor the regular expressions?

Otheriwse '111111111111111211111111111' will match /[2-5]\d{5}/.

Answer (score 1):

When using POSIX regular expressions ([deprecated by PHP 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.regex.php)) you should write the tests like this:

```
if (ereg('^[2-5][0-9]{5}$', $_POST['packageNumber']) === false)
{
   echo "The package number is not the correct format.";
}

if (ereg('^[2-5][0-9]{5}\\.[1-2]$', $_POST['packageModifier']) === false)
{
   echo "The package modifier is not the correct format.";
}

if (ereg('^[[:alnum:][:space:].-]{0,50}$', $_POST['customerNumber']) === false)
{
   echo "The customer number is not the correct format.";
}
```

Note that I anchored the regular expressions -- otherwise the customerNumber will always match (with a zero-length match).

See the [POSIX regex man page](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=7&topic=regex) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/^[2-5]\d{5}$/', $str); // 1-st
preg_match('/^[2-5]\d{5}\.[1-2]$/', $str); // 2-nd
preg_match('/^[0-9a-z\s\-\.]{0,50}$/i', $str); // 3-rd
```

Your mistakes:

1. you didn't escape slashes and finally regexp "\d" means just 'd', but "\d" means '\d'.
2. you had to anchor regesp to beginnig and the end of entire string by ^ and $ symbols.

Thats all ;)

PS: better use single quotes for string literals - they are faster and safer...